# How to write WPF Entity Framework in Ms Access database

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-6, ms-access-2007

I am new to WPF. I am unable to write how the code ms access Entity Framework delete code

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AMXCOMPANYDETAILS.AMX_SalesDBDataSet aMX_SalesDBDataSet = ((AMXCOMPANYDETAILS.AMX_SalesDBDataSet)(this.FindResource("aMX_SalesDBDataSet")));
    // Load data into the table tblContact. You can modify this code as needed.
    AMXCOMPANYDETAILS.AMX_SalesDBDataSetTableAdapters.tblContactTableAdapter aMX_SalesDBDataSettblContactTableAdapter = new AMXCOMPANYDETAILS.AMX_SalesDBDataSetTableAdapters.tblContactTableAdapter();
    aMX_SalesDBDataSettblContactTableAdapter.Fill(aMX_SalesDBDataSet.tblContact);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource tblContactViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tblContactViewSource")));

    tblContactViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();

    // Load data into the table tblContactAddress. You can modify this code as needed.
    AMXCOMPANYDETAILS.AMX_SalesDBDataSetTableAdapters.tblContactAddressTableAdapter aMX_SalesDBDataSettblContactAddressTableAdapter = new AMXCOMPANYDETAILS.AMX_SalesDBDataSetTableAdapters.tblContactAddressTableAdapter();
     AMX_SalesDBDataSettblContactAddressTableAdapter.Fill(aMX_SalesDBDataSet.tblContactAddress);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource tblContactAddressViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tblContactAddressViewSource")));
    tblContactAddressViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
}
```

Comment: I believe Access uses OLEDB, which isn't supported by Entity Framework?

Comment: thank you joe.you are awsome